# mysql combining records in same column

Tags: mysql

In a MySql db I have a list of products and I have been asked to take the value `WHERE fie_id=2` from each product and insert it into the value `WHERE fie_id=6` for the same `pro_id`

```
pro_id  fie_id  value
1       12      Kingston
1       11      kingston
1       10      Kingston
1       6       Late
1       1       Susceptible
1       7       N/A
1       9       feed
1       2       Medium bittersharp
1       5       Somerset late 19th C
1       3       Mid
2       9       Culinary
2       2       Sharp 
2       5       Devon 19th C
2       1       resistance
2       7       To Feb
2       6       Very late
2       3       3
2       10      .JPG
2       11      jpg
```

I have spent a lot of time reading about `CONCAT` and believe that this may be what I need to use but I am really struggling to figure it out. Am I on the right path? if not could someone point me in the right direction please.

So I end up with

```
pro_id  fie_id  value
1       12      Kingston
1       11      kingston
1       10      Kingston
1       6       Late, Medium bittersharp
1       1       Susceptible
1       7       N/A
1       9       feed
1       5       Somerset late 19th C
1       3       Mid
2       9       Culinary
2       5       Devon 19th C
2       1       resistance
2       7       To Feb
2       6       Very late, Sharp
2       3       3
2       10      .JPG
2       11      jpg
```

Comment: Can you post an example output ?

Comment: I have posted the example output, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you would need to execute an update query where the table joins itself.

```
UPDATE details INNER JOIN
   (
    SELECT pro_id, value FROM details WHERE fie_id = 2
   ) det
ON details.pro_id = det.pro_id
SET details.value = CONCAT(details.value, ",", det.value)
WHERE details.fie_id = 6;
```

See [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f697/1).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I have put what I want the output to look like at the top, with your code it is replacing the value in 6 with the value in 2 and not appending it. Thanks again

Comment: @user2968330 - have updated the answer a few days ago. did this work for you?